# Bar-chart with dplyr/ggplot with male/female bars side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to

Here's the example :

```
df <- read.table(text = 
  "sex  var value
  m a   1
  m a   1
  m a   0
  m b   0
  m b   0
  f a   1
  f a   0
  f b   0
  f b   1", 
header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

What I'd like to create is a bar-chart which has the proportions for each of
the `var` values, for each `sex`.

So in the above data I would have :

```
var a : 
        m : 0.6
        f : 0.5
var b : 
        m : 0
        f : 0.5
```

But expressed as a bar-chart using ggplot

Comment: What code have you tried? What was the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
group_by(var, sex) %>% 
summarise(vals = mean(value)) %>%
ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = var, y = vals, col = sex, fill = sex, group = sex)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

You can also reverse `var` and `sex`.

Comment: thank you - instead of `summarise( )` I was originally using `mutate( freq = round(100*sum(value)/n())`, with the same groupings that you have used (`group_by(var, sex)`), this didn't work. I'm not too sure that I understand why, perhaps that's something for a different post though.

Comment: as an additional note - it seems that the code you've written works whether `ungroup( )` is used or not, is this a convention or is there a reason to ungroup things here?

Comment: The data for `value` is `0` or `1`. If you want to find the `percent * `100` you can just do `vals = round(mean(value) * 100)`. Mutate only works if you want to add a new column, but based on your question, it seems like you wanted to plot the result, and not necessarily add in a new column

Comment: I `ungroup` as a standard practice because grouping can be continued throughout. I know you gave sample data, but if you wanted to do any additional work without the grouping, then it is wise to `ungroup()` especially when giving advice.